# multi-conditional counter based on dates

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science, np

I have this dataframe

```
df:
    entrance   leaving        counter
1   2012-07-01  NaT             NaN
2   2013-03-15  NaT             NaN
3   2013-03-15  2013-04-15      NaN
4   2014-06-01  NaT             NaN
5   2014-06-01  NaT             NaN
```

I want the counter which considers the two column dates and increments on `entrance` dates and decrements when there is `leaving` dates. Additionally, the following `date` column should increment by one month too.
The desired output should be:

```
df_new:
date      counter
2012-07     1
2012-08     1              
  ...      ...             
2013-03     2
  ...      ...
2014-06     4
```

I have made this line where it increments based on `entrance`, but I could not used `np.where()` to decrement if `df.entrance.notnull()'.

```
df.groupby([df['entrance'].dt.to_period("M")]).entrance.count().cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is miss-specified. The counter cannot share the index of the original DF. Here is an example of why:

```
    # Lets assume this is the DF:
    entrance   leaving        counter
1   2012-07-01  NaT             1
2   2013-03-15  NaT             2
3   2013-03-15  2013-06-15      2 ?
4   2013-06-01  NaT             3 or 4? Depends if you count the exit in prev row or not
```

Either way, here are the solutions:

```
# Load Data
s = '''     entrance   leaving        counter
1   2012-07-01  NaT             NaN
2   2013-03-15  NaT             NaN
3   2013-03-15  2013-04-15      NaN
4   2014-06-01  NaT             NaN
5   2014-06-01  NaT             NaN'''

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
df['leaving']= pd.to_datetime(df['leaving'])
df['entrance']= pd.to_datetime(df['entrance'])
```

Unambiguous solution that will not follow the original index:

```
# Counter
counter = pd.Series(1, df['entrance'].dropna()).subtract(pd.Series(1, df['leaving'].dropna()), fill_value=0).cumsum()

# If you want it monthly
counter.resample('M').last().ffill()
```

A solution that maintains the original index, but is somewhat ambiguous:

```
count_df = df.notna().cumsum()
df['counter'] = count_df['entrance'] - count_df['leaving']
```